# Node-Red Dashboard edit Header

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I want do edit the Viewport line in my Header for my Dashboard in Node-Red. Need to show my Dashboard in fullscreen mode on an iPad.
in HTML i just have to add:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />`
in my header. But I have no Idea where to edit the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dashboard-UI Template node has a mode to add things to the header

[image]

This should let you insert the bits you want.